# Can I get my video card to output a DVI and VGA signal at the same time?

Tags: dvi, vga, kvm-switch

I've got:

- a lovely 24" monitor, w/both DVI and VGA inputs,
- a personal desktop w/a Radeon HD Pro 2400 video card (both DVI and VGA outputs)
- a work laptop w/both outputs, and
- a KVM switch that handles VGA only

Right now I've got laptop connected to the monitor's VGA, and the desktop connected to the DVI.  This works, but requires me to switch the KVM and monitor input sources separately, which annoys me (I switch back & forth a lot to make skype calls & manage my music).  I'd like to feed both VGA and DVI signals out of my desktop so I can do quick things on my desktop & switch right back, but then when I'm done working, switch the monitor over to DVI to get the crisper picture.

Alas, just attaching both VGA and DVI cables to my desktop's video card did not do the trick.  Can this card be persuaded to output both signals at the same time?

Many thanks!

-Roy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to poke your Catalyst settings to enable cloning of the displays. If you're still using the stock driver then you'll need to install [Catalyst](http://ati.amd.com/products/catalystcontrolcenter/index.html).

Or use one of [these](http://sewelldirect.com/dvi-splitter-cable-vga.asp) on the DVI-I output.

Comment: Thanks!  It seems I was wrong though--my card *is* outputting signal on both monitors.  <embarrassed grin>.  I'm not sure why it didn't work before...